# how to get space as a input in String in java and use as it as null

Tags: java

i m trying to get space as a input in string in java but i m facing problem. my code is

input should be like

**case one**

```
Ram Raja Gopal
```

**output** should be

```
Gopal Ram Raja
```

**case two**

**input**

```
Ram  Gopal ( Ram is first name and Gopal is Last name)
```

**output** should be

```
Gopal Ram
```

etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class abc {

    static Scanner z = new Scanner (System.in);
    static String f;
    static String m;
    static String s;
public static void main(String args[])
{   
    f= z.next();

    ab();
    bc();

    if(f!=null && m!=null && s!=null )
    {

       System.out.println(s+" "+f+" "+m);
    }
    else if(f!=null && m==null && s!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(s+" "+f);
    }       
    else if(f!=null && m!=null && s==null)
    {
        System.out.println(f+" "+m);
    }       
    else if(f!=null && m==null && s==null)
    {
        System.out.println(f);
    }   
}

public static String ab()
{
    m=z.next();
    if(z.next().equals(" "))
    {
        m=null;
        return m;
    }
    else
    {
        m=z.next();
        return m;
    }   
}

public static String bc()
{
    s=z.next();
    if(z.next().equals(" "))
    {
        s=null;
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        s=z.next();
        return s;
    }

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z.nextLine()` if you want to read the whole line then you can split your `String` by space using `split` method

```
String[] splited = string.split("\\s+");
```

then you can print it in whatever way you like.

**Example:**

```
String str = "Ram Raja Gopal";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

now `String` array contains splited string

```
splited[0] == "Ram";
splited[1] == "Raja";
splited[2] == "Gopal";
```

now you can print it in whatever order you want.

Comment: if i will enter only Ram then it is showing runtime error "arrayoutofindex"               String name = z.nextLine();
   
  String a[]={null,null,null};
  a=name.split("\\s+");
  
 
  
  if(a[0]!=null && a[1]!=null && a[2]!=null )
  {
   System.out.println(a[2]+" "+a[0]+" "+a[1]);
  }
  
  else if (a[0]!=null && a[1]==null && a[2]==null)
  {
   System.out.println(a[0]); 
  }

Comment: @MandeepSingh if you only enter `Ram` then you don't need to split it. Just take the input and print it

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that takes the `name` in the first format. You can use [`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to split by white space, take the last entry first and use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) to join it with every name before the last in order. Like,

```
static String reArrange(String name) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
    String[] names = name.split("\\s+");
    sj.add(names[names.length - 1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
        sj.add(names[i]);
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Then you can call it with your users' input (for example)

```
System.out.println(reArrange("Ram Raja Gopal"));
System.out.println(reArrange("Ram Gopal"));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Gopal Ram Raja
Gopal Ram
```